# Getting height of a TextView before rendering it

Tags: java, android, textview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to get somehow the height of a TextView (actually before rendering it, as I it has to fit into a ListView).

I tried it with

```
Rect currentBounds = new Rect();
textview1.getPaint().getTextBounds(textview1.getText().toString(), 0,
                                       textview1.length(), currentBounds);
String size = rect.height();
```

... but I always get the same number for the height. The text always has the same width (width of the display); maybe that's an issue here?

Alternatively I tried it by means of the StaticLayout:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;                                     

StaticLayout measure = new StaticLayout(textview11.getText(), textview1.getPaint(), 
    width, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 1.0f, false);
```

But also here, I just get odd numbers I do not really know how to deal with... They are completely different from the ones from above, no matter how I convert them ...

Setting the new height of the LinearLayout is done via:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = height;
```

I hope you have been able to follow my remarks. Tell me, if I need to clarify some more things...

Thank you!

Comment: Measuring height before rendering will give you default values. I think you may find a better solution if you explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have to fit the TextView into a LinearLayout. This LinearLayout is displayed, between ListView items, when clicked. The content of the TextView is dynamically generated and differs in length. Maybe you give me an idea of a workaround to give a rough estimation of the TextView height I can expect?

Comment: try to get the height in runOnUIThread

Comment: @Pragnani could be a bit more specific about it? I don't get it ...

Comment: @androiddev007 If I don't misunderstand, you don't need to measure anything. Does this is article give what you want? http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=440